# Image not appearing in my Html script

Tags: android, html, android-layout

I have a section on my Android app called 'More Information' which is basically a few pages of Html scripts which I display using WebView with the following code -

```
InputStream fin = getAssets().open(htmlFl + ".html");
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
                 fin.read(buffer);
                 fin.close();
                 webview.loadData(new String(buffer), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

It all works fine except that the images are not appearing on any of the pages. I declare them using Html like the following -

```
<P><IMG SRC="http://www.OurWeb.co.uk/images/Icon.jpg">&  
nbsp;<span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: large;">
<B>Opening Times During Exhibition</B></SPAN></P>
```

Am I doing anything wrong using the WebView and if not is there a way around this?

Comment: You are connected to the internet when you try this?

Comment: Yes, I can get the script to work by putting the Src url in my browser on my phone and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to add `INTERNET` permission in your manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The [WebView javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) says:

> Note that, in order for your Activity to access the Internet and load web pages in a WebView, you must add the INTERNET permissions to your Android Manifest file:

Answer (score 0):

Is the image src in your example snippet actually supposed to work, or is it just filler? Because whatever your server is doing with that URL, it's [not returning an image](http://www.ourweb.co.uk/images/Icon.jpg). Maybe you've got some redirects in place you don't remember, or the entire domain is still set to be "parked" with your host?

Comment: It's just a filler, only the website is different, the real script that I use works fine in a browser on my Pc and also on the browser on my Android phone but wont work from the scripts in my app either on either my AVD or my phone. If there were any redirects or there was anyhthing wrong with the link then wouldn't it not work with either browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [SDK documentation for loadData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), notice where it says that content loaded using this method will not have access to the network.

Try using `loadDataWithBaseUrl()` instead.  You may also need to add the INTERNET permission, as others have mentioned.